# Copying all file contents into new files - Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

What I need to do is (and I have some idea, just can't get this solidified):

- Read all files in a directory (for loop)
- In loop, I need to copy the current file in the loop's contents into a new file (x.txt into x2.txt) in the same directory. This can be done with a type >> command.

I'm more confused about the looping part of it. How do I do that?

**Edit:**

This is my current script:

```
FOR %%i IN (*)
Do type %%i >> %%i2
```

Comment: Start by typing `for /?` at a prompt.

Comment: @Joey, likewise, your edit of my answer introduced a failure by not removing the `/f`.  What problems are you thinking `dir/b` introduces though?

Comment: Sorry about the `/f` one. It mangles Unicode file names under default console settings by converting output into the legacy OEM codepage, for example. Besides, since `for` is perfectly capable of iterating over files there is simply no need to call `dir` and parse file names. The second problem is that `for /f` does tokenising on its input, by default on whitespace. Thus file names with spaces won't work with a trivial `for /f` over `dir` either.

Comment: @Joey, I'll concur that the `dir /b` is not necessary, but on my WinXP machine, it handles spaces in files just fine, i.e. it doesn't tokenize on those spaces.  I can't speak to your specific claims about "legacy OEM codepage." Your solution is cleaner and probably more bullet proof, but I think mine would only fail in some very special cases.  Advantage to `dir/b` approach is that you can control the order of file processing with other `dir` flags.  regardless, I think we've given Ryan what he needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will copy each `.txt` file to a backup file with extension `.txt2`:

```
for %i in (*.txt) do type "%i" > "%i2"
```

Note that in a batch file you need to double the `%`:

```
for %%i in (*.txt) do type "%%i" > "%%i2"
```

It's not clear from your question if you want all found files dumped into the same resulting text file or if you want one-to-one copies of each.

If you just want one results file, you could also use a variant of the copy command, i.e.:

```
copy *.txt output.dat
```

Comment: This will happily copy `foo.txtbar` to `foo.txtbar2` as well; not just files ending in `.txt`.  Windows long/short filename voodoo.

Comment: `dir /b` shows me `foo.txtbar` as well.  I've read a solution for this somewhere, but can't think of where...

Comment: @JimDavis, you are correct. Not sure how to get around that though.  You?

Comment: It's ugly, but this seems to do it: `for %i in (*.txt) do if /I "%~xi" equ ".txt" type "%i" > "%i2"`

Comment: ...which is largely moot, now that I reread the question.  He wants something like `for %i ... copy "%i" "%~ni2%~xi"`.  The last page of `for /?` illustrated all the `%~xi` modifiers.