# Renaming file extensions - Stubborn left over

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am renaming file extension as such:

> 1.txt to 1.txt.new
>
> 2.txt to 2.txt.new

Now I am trying to run the command:

```
ren *.txt.new *.txt
```

However, I am now seeing:

> 1.txt.txt
>
> 2.txt.txt

How to I either rename or just remove that .new extension? Rename isn't cutting it it looks like.

Comment: have a look at Jim Davis' comments in the question I recently answered for you.  He uses `%~xi` to get the file extension.  In this case, CMD is reading the extension as the 3 letters after the final dot.  That's why you're `.new` get replaced by `.txt`.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692303/copying-all-file-contents-into-new-files-batch/10692375#10692375

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command should do the trick:

```
for %i in (*.txt.new) do @rename "%i" "%~ni"
```

Comment: +1, But I think you meant `for %i in (*.txt.new) do @rename %i %~ni`

Comment: @dbenham: you're quite right, I misread the question.  Thanks.

Comment: +1, but enclosing the arguments of `rename` in double quotes shouldn't do any harm, I think.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
RENAME *.txt.new *.
```